# Why does this whitespace appear at the top when collapsing my browser? [Bootstrap 3]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, whitespace, removing-whitespace

So I'm trying to learn how to use Bootstrap and I've been getting the hang of it, but one thing I cannot find the answer to is why does this whitespace appear at the top of my screen, but only when resized below a certain threshold (I don't have an exact pixel count but it seems to be about 992px)?

I'm using the bootstrap.min.css and then my own custom style.css below it. This is my first question on here so I'll try to get the formatting right for showing my html, but more importantly here's a picture showing what I'm talking about.

> I'm including this because I was unable to find an answer online... so usually this means it is just an extremely simple answer with a difficult way of asking!

---

[This is the Whitespace I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMNfk.jpg)
[image: This is the Whitespace I'm talking about]

---

**Here's my HTML in case you need a better look**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- My CSS -->
<link href="css/kylestyle.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 kb-header">
      <h1 class="kb-head-text">A Design Website</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 kb-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 kb-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 kb-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 kb-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt=""></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 kb-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 kb-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 kb-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 kb-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt=""></div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**and my custom .css**

```
.kb-header {
height: 800px;
background-color: #FF3300;
color: white;
}

.kb-head-text {
color: white;
font-size: 6em;
text-align: center;
}

.kb-img {
padding-top: 2em;
}
```

Thank you! I'm very new to this so I hope I've been able to provide enough information for someone to help me!

Comment: If I remember correctly, bootstrap adds padding to the container class when resizing. Have you tried inspecting it?

Comment: Have you tried using a dom inspector on it? e.g. right-click whitespace, "inspect"? Any inspector worth its salt would take you directly to the element that the whitespace belongs to.

Comment: Is there another option other than firebug? I tried doing it in Firebug but I was told that it doesn't work on local files

Comment: What else is in `kylestyle.css`? Looks fine on Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/5OXZnOpOv6

Comment: Try with plain Chrome. `Right click` -> `inspect`

Comment: When inspecting in Chrome (Thanks for the tip!) [I found this out](http://i.imgur.com/cMvDdnd.png) Although now I'm not sure what I should do to fix it...


edit: @Skelly there is nothing else in kylestyle.css

Comment: @Sifu the `.container-fluid` class goes to the top of the page, as well as the first `.row` class. However, `<div class="col-md-12 kb-header">` does not, which correct me if I'm wrong... I had my kb-header class in the wrong spot causing the default padding! Problem solved!

Comment: @meagar Sadly... I'm not allowed to answer my own question without 10 Reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting... the `.container-fluid` class was going to the top of the page, as well as the first `.row` class. However, `<div class="col-md-12 kb-header">` did not... all I had to do was put my `.kb-header` in the `.row` div

```
<div class="row kb-header">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1 class="kb-head-text">A Design Website</h1>
  </div>
</div>`
```

**Problem solved!**

Comment: can you accept your own answer, so it falls off the "unanswered" section?